# create index on timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-optimization

I have a products table which contains products. every product has an availability period. A column named BEGIN shows the date and time for start time that the product is available and END for finish availability. 
users can filter BEGIN and END time for available products. this filter can be from hours in a day to days and weeks. for example available products from now to 3 weeks in the future. 
The filtering query works great when finds some products. but if there are no products available in this period, the query searches the complete table which has millions of records and that takes too much longer. 
I have tried to index BEGIN and END but nothing changed and still takes too much time to search all table. Is the indexing the solution? I'm using mysql.
the table scehame is:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedInteger('price');
            $table->timestamp('begin')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('end')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

the query is:

```
$products = Product::where('begin' , '>=' , $request->begin)->where('end' , '<=' , $request->end)->simplePaginate(20);
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Indexing and datatypes as highly vendor-specific. Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It's mysql. I edited the question.

Comment: There is a way to structure the query in SQL which might help, but I don't know how to do it through a tool that generates the query.  You might want to ask a pure-SQL question.

Comment: `simplePagination` sounds like an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.  Part of the optimization depends on how the records will sorted; please specify.

Comment: Are you filtering on anything other than availability?  What indexes does the table have?